# What is this symbolic code transformation called?

Tags: terminology, program-transformation

I often cross this kind of code transformation (or even mathematical transformation).  (Python example, but applies to any language.)

I've go a function

```
def f(x):
  return x
```

I use it into another one.

```
def g(x):
  return f(x)*f(x)

print g(2)
```

leads to 4

But I want to remove the functional dependency, and I change the function g into

```
def g(f):
  return f*f

print g( f(2) )
```

leads to 4 too

How do you call this kind of transformation, locally turning a function into a scalar ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a specific term for it.

In general terms for functional programming there usually isn't a distinction made between passing scalar arguments and passing functions as arguments.

In the first example I could still call `g(f(2))` and it should calculate `f(f(2))*f(f(2))`, which (since `f(x)` is the identity transformation) will also result in 4 as the answer.

Comment: yes but if f(x) is time consuming (which is not the case here) g ( f(2) ) in the second case  is twice as fast as g(2) in the first case.

I'm looking for a naming for this kind of code optimization.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  In which case perhaps Memoization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is the term you're after?  I'd expect/hope the compiler and/or run-time would look after this type of optimisation though.

Comment: Thanks for the link it answer the "optimization" part of the pattern, but i was looking for a more "mathematical" term:

another example could have been, the ODE definition:

in: 
y'(t) = y(t)^2 ; y is a function.
The equation can be rewritten:
f(t) = y(t)^2 ;
To solve it, you build a new function:
f2(y,t) ->  y^2 ;

where in this case y is a real.

you've transformed  f into f2 by the same exact process I've done with g(x)


Something like "scalarization of a function" would make sense, unfortunately, it doesn't.